# Runtime .exec() funciona en eclipse pero no en Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, curl

Estoy haciendo un programa que obtiene los precios de las criptomonedas que se le pasan. Lo tengo terminado en Eclipse pero me he puesto a hacer una app en android studio y ahí no funciona.
Probando el sucio método de println he visto que el código no pasa de la línea `Process pr = rt.exec(`...

```
    public void setCurrentPrice() throws IOException{
        String response;
        
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process pr = rt.exec("curl -s -S https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=" + tokenID + "&vs_currencies=eur");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
        response = br.readLine();

        response = response.replace("{\"","").replace(tokenID,"").replace("\":eur\":", "").replace("}}", "");
        currentPrice = Double.parseDouble(response);

    }
```

Alguien sabe por qué puede ser que en un lado funcione y en otro no?
Cómo debería hacerlo en Android Studio?

Edit:
LogCat:

```
2021-08-21 00:38:45.334 16450-16450/com.example.test1 W/m.example.test: JNI critical lock held for 85.141ms on Thread[1,tid=16450,Runnable,Thread*=0xebb83810,peer=0x720c63a0,"main"]
2021-08-21 00:38:45.526 16450-16450/com.example.test1 I/Choreographer: Skipped 52 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2021-08-21 00:38:46.028 16450-16477/com.example.test1 I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=1367ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=32794868947228, Vsync=32795735613860, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=32795740009060, AnimationStart=32795752721060, PerformTraversalsStart=32795756802160, DrawStart=32796073098660, SyncQueued=32796167775160, SyncStart=32796171351960, IssueDrawCommandsStart=32796171472260, SwapBuffers=32796172797960, FrameCompleted=32796239679360, DequeueBufferDuration=1173100, QueueBufferDuration=1626300, GpuCompleted=0, 
2021-08-21 00:38:48.121 16450-16450/com.example.test1 I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 2564 bytes, containing 1 windows, 15 views
2021-08-21 00:38:49.247 16450-16450/com.example.test1 W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
2021-08-21 00:38:49.281 16450-16450/com.example.test1 W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
2021-08-21 00:39:00.787 16450-16450/com.example.test1 W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "curl": error=2, No such file or directory
2021-08-21 00:39:00.788 16450-16450/com.example.test1 W/System.err:     at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1050)
2021-08-21 00:39:00.789 16450-16450/com.example.test1 W/System.err:     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:699)
2021-08-21 00:39:00.789 16450-16450/com.example.test1 W/System.err:     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:529)
2021-08-21 00:39:00.790 16450-16450/com.example.test1 W/System.err:     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:426)
2021-08-21 00:39:00.791 16450-16450/com.example.test1 W/System.err:     at com.example.test1.Token.setCurrentPrice(Token.java:60)
2021-08-21 00:39:00.793 16450-16450/com.example.test1 W/System.err:     at com.example.test1.AddToken$1.onClick(AddToken.java:42)
2021-08-21 00:39:00.793 16450-16450/com.example.test1 W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
2021-08-21 00:39:00.794 16450-16450/com.example.test1 W/System.err:     at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
2021-08-21 00:39:00.795 16450-16450/com.example.test1 W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
2021-08-21 00:39:00.796 16450-16450/com.example.test1 W/System.err:     at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
2021-08-21 00:39:00.798 16450-16450/com.example.test1 W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
2021-08-21 00:39:00.801 16450-16450/com.example.test1 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
2021-08-21 00:39:00.803 16450-16450/com.example.test1 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
2021-08-21 00:39:00.804 16450-16450/com.example.test1 W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
2021-08-21 00:39:00.805 16450-16450/com.example.test1 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
2021-08-21 00:39:00.807 16450-16450/com.example.test1 W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2021-08-21 00:39:00.810 16450-16450/com.example.test1 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
2021-08-21 00:39:00.811 16450-16450/com.example.test1 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
2021-08-21 00:39:00.814 16450-16450/com.example.test1 W/System.err: Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
2021-08-21 00:39:00.815 16450-16450/com.example.test1 W/System.err:     at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
2021-08-21 00:39:00.817 16450-16450/com.example.test1 W/System.err:     at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:133)
2021-08-21 00:39:00.818 16450-16450/com.example.test1 W/System.err:     at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:141)
2021-08-21 00:39:00.819 16450-16450/com.example.test1 W/System.err:     at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
2021-08-21 00:39:00.820 16450-16450/com.example.test1 W/System.err:     ... 17 more
2021-08-21 00:39:01.940 16450-16450/com.example.test1 D/AutofillManager: onActivityFinishing(): calling cancelLocked()
```

Comment: De Android no se mucho, pero estoy casi seguro que no tienes disponible el comando `curl` y por eso no funciona.

Comment: Debe funcionar, que se muestra en el LogCat

Comment: @E.Betanzos En el LogCat (incluido ahora en la pregunta) he visto esto: 2021-08-21 00:36:52.424 16450-16450/com.example.test1 W/System.err:     at com.example.test1.Token.setCurrentPrice(Token.java:60)
Que es la línea en la que deja de ejecutarse el programa

Comment: matsrom agrega la clase que indico en mi respuesta AddToken.java , y menciona cual es la linea 42, al parecer este mètodo lo estas llamando desde un botòn pero tienen un problema el mètodo.

Comment: @matsrom está pasando exactamente lo que te comenté: no tienes disponible el comando `curl`. De ahí el error que te dá al invocar el método `Runtime.exec()`: `error=2, No such file or directory`. Esto ocurre porque no se encuentra el ejecutable del comando.

Answer (score 1):

Como te comentaba, ya sea usando Eclipse o Android Studio el ejecutar un proceso deberìa funcionar con tu còdigo:

```
 Process pr = rt.exec("curl -s -S https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=" + tokenID + "&vs_currencies=eur");
```

pero si revisas el LogCat se puede ver el problema:

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "curl": error=2, No such file
> or directory 2021-08-21 00:39:00.788 16450-16450/com.example.test1
> W/System.err:     at
> at com.example.test1.AddToken$1.onClick(AddToken.java:42)
> java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1050)     at
> com.example.test1.Token.setCurrentPrice(Token.java:60) W/System.err:
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory

El error indica que hay un directorio el cual no existe, el problema ocurre en la clase AddToken.java linea 42, agrega esta clase e indica la linea por favor...